# SSMA MySql to MsSql Null Value Error

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-migration-assi

The MySQL contains some tables with some zero date time : '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. When using SSMA to migrate the database into MsSql I am facing the error about cannot insert DbNull. This is understandable since neither MySql or MsSql has this field nullable.

What I do not understand is that I changed SSMA's Default Projet setting to Replace with a constant all zero-date Not Null columns. The constant I choose is : 1900-01-01.
[image]

Is there any other settings that must be set?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found is to go inside the MySql database, alter every table that is having a default value with zero based datetime to allow null. Then, I update every of these fields to update zero based value to null. From here, using the ssma tool work since their is no more zero based date time. This is far from being perfect but it works.